# Using the like statement in MYSQL without the order mattering

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-like

Is there a way to use the like statement in MYSQL without the order mattering? For example:

```
WHERE Country LIKE '%land1%land2%';
```

and

```
WHERE Country LIKE '%land2%land1%';
```

are two completely different statements. While the first one only gets data from rows that contains the words land1, and land2 in that specific order, the second one only gets data from rows that contains the words land2, and land1 in *that* specific order. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html take a look @ this

Comment: you can WHERE Country LIKE '%land1%' AND Country LIKE '%land2%';

Comment: I've removed the tag keywords from your post topic.   See this question on meta for more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: @VMcreator Smart, smart, smart.

Comment: You could have also used both of the two expressions you started with tied together with OR.

Comment: @shawnt00 But wouldn't that make it so that if it has either land1, OR land2, it would get the results? I need BOTH land1, AND land2, without the order mattering.

Comment: I meant `Country like '%land1%land2%' or Country like '%land2%land1%'`

Answer (score 2):

Use an `AND` boolean operator with two independent `LIKE` clauses.

```
WHERE Country LIKE '%land2' AND Country LIKE '%land1%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Example using [Regexp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
WHERE Country REGEXP '.*(land[12]){2}.*';
```

Comment: I thought so too, but this would match `land2land2` and `land1land1`, which may not be intended.

Comment: there are other reasons i wouldn't do this, but it may be handy for someone who does need more complicated `like` queries

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Country REGEXP 'land1|land2';
```

Which will be output as same as:

```
WHERE (Country LIKE '%land1%' OR Country LIKE '%land2%');
```

Comment: But wouldn't that make it so that if it has either land1, OR land2, it would get the results? I need BOTH land1, AND land2, without the order mattering.